# Salesforce Bulk API: Custom objects in polymorphic fields

Tags: salesforce, polymorphic-associations, bulk

Does Bulk API Upsert support custom objects in polymporphic fields?
It does support polymorphic fields (e.g. Event.What) and custom objects - but when I try to upsert an event with a custom object in What I get an error.

Here is the csv file uploaded (to upsert an event):

```
"Invoice__c:What.ExtId__c","Subject","OwnerId","Type__c","ExtId__c"
"INV_686850","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","00558000001bxXX","EMail","EVT_10022339"
```

and here is the error message:

> Failed  InvalidBatch : Entity type for
>   the polymorphic foreign key reference: What didn't match the supplied
>   type: Invoice__c

"Track Activities" is enabled for Invoice__c - and looking into workbench the relationship between Event and Invoice__c is visible on both sides of the relationship. It is also possible to add an event to an Invoice__c in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

For your header value "Invoice__c:What.ExtId__c", remove the __c for the Entity Type. "Invoice:What.ExtId__c".

Even though its a custom entity, the bulk api does not want the __c suffix. This is not documented anywhere I could find.

Answer (score 1):

You can find part of the information here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/relationship_fields_in_a_header_row__2_0.htm